# Ignoring blank fields when submitting rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using several dropdowns to create a search and they are submitting '' if the user doesn't select one. I need a catchall, something like * in SQL as the default value. ie if I have 5 brands in a dropdown, I want the default query to be all 5 brands. Something like Brand.where(brand: ALL). Thanks in advance.

```
<%= select_tag(:brand, options_for_select(["Brand 1","Brand 2","Brand 3","Brand 4","Other"].map{ |num| [num,num] }),id: 'brand', prompt: 'Brand', class: "table") %>
```

Comment: Any examples of what you have so far?

Comment: <%= select_tag(:brand, options_for_select(["Brand 1","Brand 2","Brand 3","Brand 4","Other"].map{ |num| [num,num] }),id: 'brand', prompt: 'Brand', class: "table") %> is an example.

So the default is Brand and I want the selected value to be ALL, so its not actually filtering anything.

Comment: Can you make another option for "all" and assign the options to the attribute how you want in the controller? When create() assign the brand param when selected as 'all' to how you want it before save.

Comment: Brand.where(brand: :all) isn't a valid statement, so don't think that would work.

Comment: I don't want you to do a query...? When the form is submitted have the brand parameter assigned as 'all'. Then in the controller create() method grab the parameter value, if its 'all' assign the attribute how you want. Then allow it to continue and save.

Comment: Understood, makes sense but I'm using multiple criteria so it would get overly complicated.

Comment: Please post your log of the POST., Please edit answer to include this, not as a comment.

Comment: Started GET "/listings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&brand=&size=&year=&color=&blank="
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "brand"=>"", "size"=>"", "year"=>"", "color"=>"", "blank"=>""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `include_blank` and a `prompt` in your selects.

```
select_tag(..., include_blank: true, prompt: 'All')
```

Now the first entry in the dropdown will have a blank value, and display "All" for its label.

You'll then need to just make sure you don't use that criteria when you query, something like this (you didn't post any code, so I don't know your model):

```
class MyController ...

  def show
    @items = Item.all
    @items = @items.where(brand: params[:brand]) if params[:brand].present?
    @items = @items.where(size: params[:size]) if params[:size].present?
    @items = @items.where(year: params[:year]) if params[:year].present?
    @items = @items.where(color: params[:color]) if params[:color].present?
  end

end
```

Comment: spot on - I was overcomplicating it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_brand, -> (brand) { where brand: brand }
  # put more scopes for the other drop-down boxes
end
```

product_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @products = Product.all
    @products = @products.by_brand(params[:brand]) unless params[:brand].blank?
    # more filtering here
  end
end
```